# Why does this passlib hashing script create a new result every time I run the script?

Tags: python, hash, passwords, salt, passlib

I'm using the following [script from the passlib docs](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/#welcome) to hash a password:

```
# import the hash algorithm                                                         
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt                                               

# generate new salt, and hash a password
hash = sha256_crypt.encrypt("toomanysecrets")
print hash  # <== WHY IS THIS ALWAYS A DIFFERENT STRING?
# verifying the password
print sha256_crypt.verify("toomanysecrets", hash)  # Outputs "True"
print sha256_crypt.verify("joshua", hash)  # Outputs "False"
```

It seems odd that `sha256_crypt.verify` would be able to verify multiple different hashes as "toomanysecrets" - why isn't there just one hash for this password?

Comment: `generate new salt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash result depends on the input and [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). Where the salt - it is randomly generated value which is included in the output string together with result of hashing. That is why for each call sha256_crypt.encrypt output string looks random, but password verification ability is preserved.